# Insert Unicode characters using alias like LaTeX

Tags: windows, parser, unicode

When I am on a Zoom session or messaging a group on Discord or messenger (on PC, Windows 10) about math/computer science related topics, I frequently run into situations where it is easier for me to explain concepts by giving an example using a mathematical formula, which consists of mathematical symbols. I have been just opening another browser to search "Math Unicode" and copy and paste the Unicode characters to form the formulas I needed. If the example is pretty long, then it gets tedious really fast.

So, I was wondering if there was a software that I can just have running on the background that translates a portion of a text with a syntax similar to LaTeX in a textbox that is focused when I click a hotkey.

For example, if I was in a Zoom session, had `$0^\ast(1\cup\epsilon)0^\ast(1\cup\epsilon)0^\ast$` written on the chat box, and I clicked a hotkey, say `CTRL+ALT+T`, then the software translates it into `0*(1∪ε)0*(1∪ε)0*`.

I know that Windows have a feature where I can insert Unicode characters using the Unicode, but that requires some memorization, and I probably will still have a browser open to look up that Unicode. For me, since I'm currently learning LaTeX, it's easier to remember the symbols using some sort of alias like `\sigma`, `\subset`, `\cap`, etc. Also, I want it to be easier to make things superscript and subscript quickly (ex. `$F=\{q_{a1}, q_a\}$`→`F={qₐ₁,qₐ}`).

Is such software even possible? If it does, is there any software that does a similar thing?

The most important thing I am looking for is

- Quick and easy way to insert Unicode characters using some sort of alias
- Quick and easy way to format text (superscript, subscript, overline)
- Works in any application where I can type (Zoom, Discord, Chrome, Notepad)

Thank you for reading through this, and I will be grateful for any recommendations.

Comment: While it would take some doing to set up your needed aliases, [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) should be able to handle it.

Comment: Formating text in arbitrary programs is simply not possible. That's a feature each program provides (or not) and how it decides to display text. You can, at most, show any Unicode characters that simulate the real format, if that suffices.